# Can Saxon XSLT save XML to eXist-db?

Tags: saxon, exist-db

Can Saxon XSLT save XML to eXist-db?  I've searched documentation and forums, but could not find anything explicitly documented.  I can read from eXist-db with `doc('http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/winequest/mysave.xql')`, but don't see an explicit way to write XML.  I've tried this, but it silently doesn't execute mysave.xql.

```
<xsl:result-document href="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/mysave.xql">
    <xsl:sequence select="$node"/>
</xsl:result-document>
```

I'm guessing Saxon doesn't see http: as a viable result-document destination, i.e. via a POST.  Or to put it another way, I'm looking to send an http POST of XML content to Xquery on eXist-db, so it can store that XML.  I can probably alternatively URL encode a little XML using `doc($url)`, but that will quickly run into limits.

So what is the preferred mechanism for Saxon XSLT to save XML to eXist-db?

Comment: I am not too familiar with eXist-db but I think recent versions do support the XPath 3.1 function `fn:transform` (by delegating it to Saxon) and that way you could use that function to run a transformation to get a map of the result documents and then use any XQuery mechanism eXist-db offers to store a document in the db by processing the map.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the suggestion.  The main issue with that is it would require initiating from eXist-db, rather than initiating from Saxon.  Whatever pipeline is controlling the flow would have to start from eXist-db, then have eXist-db call a transform in Saxon, returning the results to eXist-db to store.  That's an entirely different architecture than the pipeline starting in Saxon, then storing some result in eXist-db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke Saxon from Java you can call `Xslt30Transformer.setResultDocumentHandler(...)` to supply a callback function which will be invoked to handle the output of `xsl:result-document` instructions. The callback function is supplied with a URI, and returns a `Destination` which Saxon will write to. The `Destination` can be anything you like; you can implement the logic here to write the result document to an eXist database.

Comment: Thanks, Michael, that looks like the answer I was looking for.  The trick being implementing the logic to write the result document to eXist-db.  If anyone has some sample code for this they are willing to share, that would be greatly appreciated.  If not, I'll start from scratch and we'll see how far I can get with it.

Comment: eXist has several interfaces that could be used to receive and store data. XML-RPC, WebDAV, and REST. Perhaps REST is the simplest. Submit an HTTP PUT request. See https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/devguide_rest. Another option with the REST interface is to write your own XQuery module that receives payloads and stores them.

Comment: The simplest is probably for your Destination object to either subclass or delegate to the `net.sf.saxon.s9api.Serializer` class, and to arrange that on completion (when `close()` is called) an HTTP PUT request is issued to write the document to the database,